# how to use pivot table or any other method to reindex a dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, pivot-table

I have a dataframe with 100 rows and 102 columns that looks like:

```
 sr#,        Text,    Val1,      Val2,    Val3,    Val4,.........., Val100        
 1,        any text,   1,          1,      1,        0,...........,   0   
 2,        any text,   0,          0,      0,        1,...........,   1   
 3,        any text,   1,          0,      1,        1,...........,   1
           .......
           .......
100,       any text,   1,          0,      0,        1,...........,   1
```

I want to show all values as the second column and Text as the column headers. The values of the columns change accrodingly. The resulting dataframe will be:

```
sr#,        Values,  any text,      any text,   any text,........, any text        
 1,          Val1,      1,             0,           1,...........,     1   
 2,          Val2,      1,             0,           0,...........,     0   
 3,          Val3,      1,             0,           1,...........,     0
 4,          Val4,      0,             1,           1,...........,     1
           .......
           .......
100,       Val100,      0,             1,           1,...........,     1
```

I will really appreciate some help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like what you want is pandas.DataFrame.transpose. Note that you will need to set as index the column 'Text' before transposing it. You can do that with pandas.DataFrame.set_index

Something like:

```
new_df = df.set_index('Text').transpose()
```

should do the trick.

Comment: agreed on what you've said here, but you should probably show some sample code for OP to test out!

Answer (score 0):

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html

Please have a look in the above link. Basically:

```
df = df.T # or df.transpose()
```